# .click() giving access denied in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

When trying to invoke a `.click()` of an `anchor` tag to `auto click` the url.
The code is working fine in all browsers except `Internet Explorer` **v11**.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
var strContent = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
var HTML_APS = strContent;
var data = new Blob([HTML_APS]);
var temp_link = document.createElement('a');
temp_link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
temp_link.download = "report_html.htm";
temp_link.type = "text/html";
temp_link.style = "display:none";
document.body.appendChild(temp_link);
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
  temp_link.click();
  temp_link.remove();
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skoley/hcqn9m5a/).

Comment: for IE, use `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` - https://jsfiddle.net/hcqn9m5a/3/

Comment: There's no jQuery code here, why do you have that tag?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For IE, you can use `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob`

so, cross browser, the code would be

```
var strContent = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
var HTML_APS = strContent;
var data = new Blob([HTML_APS]);

if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, "report_html.htm");
  } else {
    var temp_link = document.createElement('a');
    temp_link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    temp_link.download = "report_html.htm";
    temp_link.type = "text/html";
    document.body.appendChild(temp_link);
    temp_link.click();
    temp_link.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: so for IE "var data = new Blob([HTML_APS]);"  this will not work instead This code "navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, "report_html.htm")" should be implemented ?

Comment: look at the code ... `var data = new Blob([HTML_APS]);` is for ALL browsers ... it's only HOW you download it that is different

Answer (score 1):

When used download attribute an anchor, this signifies that the browser should download the resource the anchor points to rather than navigate to it. 
It doesn't support IE11.
For reference [click here](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988774/ie-10-script5-access-is-denied-error-on-anchor-click-event) SO answer, the 'download' attribute has not been implemented in Internet Explorer.

> The download attribute is not implemented in Internet Explorer.
>
> http://caniuse.com/download
>
> For Internet explorer you can use the "SaveAs" command.